# Why does my model look "patchy" after I enable smooth shading on it?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How I do I fix those strange patches? I tried hours of subdividing areas and such but to no luck.. Is there a simple fix? Could someone people help, I'd be glad to share the Blender file I just really need to get this finished as soon as possible.

Blender file, would be amazing if you could help :)

Comment: Man, you need to retopologize your mesh, cause now it looks like a total mess :O. First recalculate normals (Ctrl+N), then get rid of triangles and ngons (use knife (K) to connect vertices). Also post your .blend file via pasteall.org so we may help you clean this 
nightmarish topology.

Comment: @Gonzou No, don't use PasteAll. Please use [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). This keeps the model around so that if someone comes along a year or two later, they can still look at it. PasteAll removes .blends after a few months.

Comment: @Gonzou , I've added the file, could you maybe take a look at it and help me fix it? :)

Comment: I'll try to make a quick retopo of your model tomorrow. I'll also show you some topology flow tips. Stay tuned ;).

Comment: @user18623 can you ask a new question on topology on a different post, so that Gonzou's help is useful to others, and the questions and answers stay stay organized?

Comment: @user18623 please ask a new question (something like 'how to retopologize my model?') as cegaton suggested. I nearly finished the retopo work and want to show you some tips, which demand a new answer.

Comment: @Gonzou done http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39791/how-to-retopologize-my-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normals appear to be inverted in those areas. In edit mode, select the whole mesh (A key) and then recalculate the normals by pressing Ctrl + N (or using the menus: Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside).

Comment: @user18623 give the guy his props... accept his answer. That's how folks 'round here get paid.