# Fastest method for retopology in Blender?

Tags: topology

I've modeled a head in Zbrush but it's a very dense mesh. This is my very first 3D project so I'm not really sure how to go about doing the retopology. Can anyone point me toward some good tutorials or provide an answer to help me?

This is what I'm trying to get a low-poly mesh for (I'm trying to make a video game)
[image]

When I try to do retopology in Zbrush, this is what I get:

[image]

As you can probably see, there are 9 holes in the retopo.

Comment: Please see these treads: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology? and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly

Comment: For some tips please see also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39791/how-to-retopologize-my-model

Comment: Why don't you retopologize it inside zbrush? It is much more powerful tool and also a lot better suited in retopology.

Comment: I've tried, but I always seem to end up with holes in my retopology. No matter how many times I redraw the curves, certain areas always end up with no new faces.

Comment: @Jerryno : that zbrush is a more powerful tool and that is a lot better suited in retopology is your very personal point of view. If you tell this here,you have to be careful :D

Comment: @Marietto some things can be backed up with objective reasons, others are indeed just personal preferences and opinions. I have both good experience with zbrush and blender retopo and can objectively compare them for anyone interested. The best place would be chat probably, I am always open for a good cg talk

Comment: @AquielWomble Hi, the reason you are getting holes is that the tool that you are using is not meant for extensive retopo work. Please work with Zsphere retopology for best results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiKaWl4rcyc. You can also use Zremesher for the base and then refine the result with Zshere retopo where it is needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RowfkBTarE

Comment: @Marietto: look at 22k+ Jerryno BSE reputation points (just hover cursor over his name link)... those don't come free, he should know what he says... ;) and "here" is not an hostile place towards other programs: what fits better, or is preferred, is always welcome...

Comment: I've realized that I wasn't sculpting with Dynamesh on. I'd really like to use the Zremesher, but when I turn Dynamesh on it completely messes up my model. Is there any way to project the non-dynamesh model on a dynamesh model?

Comment: @Jerryno : don't take my words as an offence, I just wanted to challenge you only a bit. But now I tell you something seriously. I think that talking about objectivity is not accurate in this area,because it is tied with the mathematic / geometry. Infact,is better to talk about inter-subjectivity. Infact there are a common use to make things and always an alternative way. For this reason,I don't see where is the objectivity. For me the objectivity happens when everybody makes the same thing in the same circumstances. But this is *objectively* not possible :)

Comment: @AquielWomble Yes there is a way to project one mesh onto another through Subtool > Project. This matter would be better to solve on a zbrush forum though.

Comment: @Marietto no offence taken. The end-result (retopo) can be both made with Blender or Zbrush. That is not up to discussion. The way and how fast you get this result is. We can objectively measure how many polygons does each program handle, how well and how fast it snaps to the hi-res, how fast it is to undo, how many clicks and actions does it take, etc. These can be measured objectively. Don't take me wrong, zbrush is not perfect. There are even better tools for retopo like 3Dcoat or topogun. But they all would humiliate Blender. However Blender is free and that is a big big strength.

Comment: @Jerryno : you said : These can be measured objectively : no,man. it depends about the tool that you use to make the measurement and I think not only about this....To be clear : I don't know zbrush and I know only a little blender,so,I will not talk deeply to these tools,I limit myself only to talk in general way. Infact,when I read and hear someone that talks about the objectivity my antennas are straightened.

Comment: @Jerryno ...The objectivity does not exist for everything related to the human thought,that's all. Perhaps there could be some event on the environment where we live,like the speed of light and sound that could be objective datas,but I'm not sure because the only ones that can measure them are again the humans and they can do it only using their rational capacities and different kind of tools that could be different in everyone.

Comment: @Marietto I don't know what you are smoking, but I want it. That is some philosophy off topic that scientist only laugh at. Yeah the reality is only dream, everything are just pictures on some cave wall and nothing actually exist - it is only on our minds. I think I am done talking.

Comment: Yes,I know that I'm off topic,so I can stop this conversation here,but I'm studiying psychology and philosophy,so these are my areas of interest. To tell that nothing actually exist is not correct and I think that a good philosopher don't think at that. I like mor "Cogito ergo sum" or better "I feel ergo sum" :D