# What's the best way to avoid ngons and tris in a model?

Tags: modeling

Basically the question says it all. I'm asking this because I keep getting a lot of ngons and tris with the model I'm working on. And I plan on letting people use this model for whatever they want(whether it be mods or animations) and I don't want it to be filled with ngons and tris.

Comment: This is pretty broad and mainly oponion based. There really is no single way to avoid them other than not creating them in the first place. Also [knowing good topology](http://topologyguides.com) may help

Comment: suggested reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-tris and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2935#2935 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39791/how-to-retopologize-my-model/39829#39829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has worked best for me so far is to (A) start with quad-based meshes, such as cubes, UV spheres, and cylinders and then (B) add new geometry by using loop cuts (Ctrl+R) and extruding faces (E) in edit mode.

You can then move vertices manually in edit mode or use sculpt mode (with Dyntopo off) to shape your model without adding vertices or creating ngons.